# Vuetify Combobox - open dropdown on icon click

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a search input field with a history of previous searches on a dropdown, like, for example the search field in the Intellij editor.

I'm new to Vuetify and from what I can see so far it looks like Combobox is the best component to use.

I would like the dropdown to only open if you click the dropdown icon. At the moment the dropdown opens when you click in the text input field. From the documentation is looks like prop `:menu-props="{openOnClick: false}"` might be what I need, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone give me pointer in the right direction?

https://codepen.io/damianhelme/pen/zMXJvb

```
<v-combobox
   v-model="search"
   :items="searchHistory"
   label="Search"
   :menu-props="{openOnClick: false}"
></v-combobox>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      search: '',
      searchHistory: [
        'Apple',
        'Banana',
        'Pear'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: `openOnClick: false` expected behavior would presumably be that when you click the input component, that menu doesn't get opened. This seems not to be working, so perhaps it's a bug (also setting custom activator as per v-menu docs is apparently not working).  You wrote `I would like the dropdown to only open if you click the dropdown icon.` - so even if that prop worked as expected, I presume menu would open as soon as you start typing. Is that intended? You can try setting `@click.stop` on v-autocomplete`, but that would prevent closing on-click as well.I suggest ask devs to see if thats bug

Comment: thanks @Traxo, I would like the menu to stay closed while typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:
Updated pen with custom `append` slot to deal with icon state:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrjzRL

---

If you want to open (and close) the combobox only on icon-click, try this trick:

```
<v-combobox
    :menu-props="{value: autoselectMenu}"
    @click:append="toggle"
></v-combobox>
```

Pass custom `value` to menu - this indicates whether menu should be opened/closed.
Then change that value only on icon-click by using `:append-icon-cb` prop.

```
data () {
  return {
    autoselectMenu: false,
// ...
methods: {
  toggle() {
    this.autoselectMenu = !this.autoselectMenu
  }
// ...
```

So for any other case when you want to open or close the menu, just change that custom value i.e. `autoselectMenu`.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMXXQx)

Comment: You can do `:append-icon-cb="this.autoselectMenu = !this.autoselectMenu` inline. But nice trick !

Comment: @Toodoo Yes, and also `append-icon-cb` is deprecated and we should  `@click:append` instead, lol. But used custom function if we need to reuse it in some other cases perhaps. Need to test this approach to see if it's buggy tho?

Comment: thanks @Traxo. I'm curious about '@click:append="toggle"', I haven't seen that kind of statement before. I'm guessing that's how you bind an event listener to a slot in a component. Do you know if that's documented anywhere? I can't find it in the Vuejs docs.
Also, in the Codepen example, I see that the dropdown icon turns upside down when you start typing even though the menu hasn't opened. Is there any easy way to stop that happening?

Comment: @DamianHelme `@click:append` is documented for textfields (see Events tab) at least https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#api, devs are very busy so not everything is actually documented. There are vuetify warnings and release notes tho. See update on how to deal with icon state.

Comment: I have been trying to apply `:menu-props="{ closeOnClick: true, closeOnContentClick: true, openOnClick: false, maxHeight: 200 }"` on v-combobox and v-autocomplete both are not working.
vuetify version i'm using 1.5.14
can any one help!!!!